# Refresh HTML Page in Browser Automatically on Timer - Every 15 Min

Tags: html, ajax, browser, refresh

Is it possible to automatically refresh a website on a timer, like every 15 minutes?  Basically, we will be making updates to a website and we want it to automatically refresh so it will show up on a big monitor we have which is controlled from a different computer.

So instead of going to that other computer to click refresh when changes are made, it would just automatically refresh so we can keep it up there.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do really 'clever' stuff really easy with likes of ajax these days to poll content and say for example add a <div> to show the latest information such as the bbc football news page http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/front_page/9573292.stm

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Place this inside `<head>` to refresh page after 900 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900"> <!-- Refresh every 15 minutes -->
```

For what it's worth, the [w3c has officially deprecated this feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element), but browsers continue to support this feature.  For your purposes, this is an ideal solution.  It's just not a recommended solution for "public" (www)-facing web sites any more.

Comment: good method if you have a page that contains few elements and not a lot of loading material . but if you have a page that contains a lot of details , i suggest using AJAX or JQUERY

Answer (score 5):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
//refresh the page after 900,000 miliseconds (15 minutes)


//reload the page (javascript has many ways of doing this)
location.reload();
},900000);
```

That should help.

Comment: 15000 milliseconds probably isn't 15 minutes.

Comment: In fact, google has a super fast cheat for this:

https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=15+minutes+to+milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

You dont even need js to do this! Look at the refresh meta tag:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm
You can use this to refresh the page on any interval.

Answer (score 2):

Although the refresh meta tag is the simpler solution to update information on a webpage it is also a pretty old and dated solution.

Imagine for example that Google maps would need to refresh the whole page when you pan the map view. There is where ajax comes in, you can find a lot information about it online like [this](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=10) for example.

I don't know specifically what was your intention but just wanted to give this background information, if just a refresh is really what you need then the answers from *box86rowh* and *ckittel* is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the url in the querystring, and then just load it in a frame

source:  javascriptkit.com

```
<script>
<!--
should range from 0 to 59
var limit="0:30"
if (document.images){
    var parselimit = limit.split(":")
    parselimit = parselimit[0]*60+parselimit[1]*1
}
function beginrefresh(){
    if (!document.images)
        return
    if (parselimit == 1)
        window.location.reload()
    else{ 
        parselimit -= 1
        curmin = Math.floor(parselimit/60)
        cursec = parselimit%60
        if (curmin!=0)
            curtime = curmin+" minutes and "+cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
        else
            curtime = cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
        window.status = curtime
        setTimeout("beginrefresh()",200)
    }
}

 window.onload = beginrefresh
 //-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="" id="refreshResults" frameborder="0" width="1800" height="1800"></iframe>
```

```
<script>

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    $(function(){
        $("#refreshResults").attr('src','<%=Request.Querystring("w")%>');
    });

</script>
```