# Refresh the specific html file every second externally

Tags: refresh

I have to see one website which gives out the information.
But the website is static, it doesn't refresh automatically.

So, I have to refresh html externally.
Is there any browser that does it? or Is there any way that I can do it.
Is it possible? As a third viewer of the website, do something about the 
refresh of the specific website...

I saw : [Refresh HTML Page in Browser Automatically on Timer - Every 15 Min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206694/refresh-html-page-in-browser-automatically-on-timer-every-15-min)
(I did the homework)
But this is for the people who can have server access. Not this case. I have no access to this website.  And they won't insert this line for the sake of themselves. Let's assume this way.

I might bring the website and display one my server using their url?
Any help would be welcomed. Thanks in advance ~

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has extensions that claim to do this (e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc).  I haven't actually tried any of them, though.