# svg edit in notepad and stream in browser

Tags: c, svg

I have a `gauge.svg` file that I show in browser. I have written a c code to move its needle by replacing the respective values in notepad. I change the values of attribute `d` in following code and it works perfect. The needle moves but I need to reload the page in my browser to get the latest values displayed.

```
<path
   style="fill:#ff6600;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
   id="Needle"
   d="m 58.959938,203.32024 -1.951087,-3.49186 90.199129,-53.83452 4.87751,8.72951 z"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   webpanel:type="needle"
   inkscape:transform-center-x="43.795592"
   inkscape:transform-center-y="25.652449" 

/>
```

But I don't want to reload the page again and again. I want it to auto update from changed values in notepad. Any suggestions please? I really need help.

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: If you need this just for your development environment you can use LiveReload http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ok im kind of a kind of a novice but here's my go.

How about using an iFrame as the window that displays the needle and puting a timer that refreshes the iframe every 5 seconds for example?

Comment: Add into your HTML file this tag:     <iframe src="HTML FILE SOURCE GOES HERE"></iframe>    This answer will help you create a timer that rehreshes the content. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206694/refresh-html-page-in-browser-automatically-on-timer-every-15-min   The content refresh coding should be placed inside your source html file.

Comment: my file is in xml, can you show me where to place the tag and timer. here is how the file looks like
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
    <svg
    xmlns:webpanel="http://www.evexiallc.com"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    . ..
    ....
    </svg>

Thank You so much

Comment: No idea friend, as i said im quite the novice in this matters. Sounds easy to solve though, im sure someone else will answer this.

Comment: Thanks. Hoping for someone to get me through it :)

Comment: When you say "C code", do you mean a CGI script?  Or do you mean a program you run independently from the webserver that updates the SVG file?

Comment: The meta refresh needs to go in the HTML `<head>` section. You can't put it in the SVG.  Are you not embedding the SVG in an HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it your way is not a very elegant solution.  However you can get an HTML page to reload using meta refresh.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

There are much better ways though.

Comment: I would definetely agree that it is not a very elegant solution but isn't what i described meta-refresh?

Comment: Sorry Nicholas. I didn't notice that you had pointed to that solution.